# why the color word is used in this way: "dark" chocolate and "black" coffee

Tags: differences

Both colors of dark chocolate and black coffee are the same to me. Why the color words used are different?
Thanks!

Comment: Similar color adjectives are often arbitrary.

Comment: Usage. 'Dark coffee' usually refers to darker beans (they come in different shades), and then there's 'dark roast coffee'. It's handy to have a different descriptor.

Comment: I thought there were only two types of chocolate : plain and milk.

Comment: @Nigel J Plain/dark, milk and white are the three main classes in the UK (though some brands get more technical, specifying percentage of cocoa solids for 'ultra-dark' etc).

Comment: Because language is what it is, and not what somebody thinks it should be.

Comment: of course *dark* is not a colour word, as in specifying a colour

Answer (score 1):

"Dark chocolate" is a marketing term for what used to be marketed as "plain chocolate". "Plain chocolate" is the older term but "dark chocolate" has become [more popular](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bar+of+plain+chocolate%2Cbar+of+dark+chocolate&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3). (I added the words "bar of" in an attempt to exclude false positives where the phrase "dark chocolate" is part of the description of something by its colour.)

[Plain chocolate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_chocolate) is so called to distinguish it from milk chocolate: no milk is added in making it. "Dark" patently refers to its colour. As for why the word "dark" is used to denote such chocolate by its colour: what other word would be better? The whole term must distinguish it from milk chocolate, and both products are brown.

Comment: "What other word would be better?" The difficulty here is that, for coffee, *black coffee* is coffee with no milk added. *Dark chocolate* is chocolate with no milk added. So, at least in the abstract, *black* would be just as good for meaning "no milk added" while also referring to color. BTW, the explanation that *dark chocolate* was the marketed label is good (thank you for the Ngrams and the selectivity) - thank you.